# php - Output date in d-m-Y format from MySQL timestamp column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table which process timestamp when someone signup for my service. The timestamp works correctly and inserts whole time in database but i need only Date,Month and Year format in it. Please have a look at my code:

```
    if((!isset($_SESSION['USER'])) || (!isset($_SESSION['UID'])) || (!isset($_SESSION['UTYPE'])) || (($_SESSION['UTYPE']!='D') && ($_SESSION['UTYPE']!='F') && ($_SESSION['UTYPE']!='T')))
{
    header( 'Location: login.html' );
}
else
{
    include 'connection.php';
    include 'constants.php';

    $file_name = "Avanti-Website-Leads-".date('dmy-His');

    echo "<html><head>";
    ?>
    <script src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function export2excel(file_name)
    {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = file_name+".xls";
        link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('body').html());
        link.click();
    }
    </script>

    <?php

    echo "</head><body onload=\"export2excel('".$file_name."')\" >";

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbhost.";dbname=".$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    unset($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if(($_SESSION['UTYPE']=='D')||($_SESSION['UTYPE']=='F'))
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `bookavanti` where uid = ".$_SESSION['UID']." order by `bookavanti`.`lastupdate` DESC";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM bookavanti order by lastupdate";
    }

    $sql = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();
    $affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();
    if($affected_rows>0)
    {
        echo "<table style='font-size:12px;text-align:center;'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Booking Time</th><th>Booking Type</th><th>Client Name</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Contact No.</th><th>Address</th><th>Pin Code</th><th>City</th><th>State</th></tr>";
        for ($i=0; $i < $affected_rows; $i++)
        {
            $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $x = explode('-',$row['lastupdate'],0);
            echo "<tr><td>".date("m.d.y",$x)."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['email']."</td><td>".$row['contact']."</td><td>".$row['address']."</td><td>".$row['pin']."</td><td>".$row['city']."</td><td>".$row['state']."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    echo "</body></html>";
```

I believe the lines

```
$x = explode('-',$row['lastupdate'],0);
        echo "<tr><td>".date("m.d.y",$x)."</td>
```

have problem. What should i do to output timestamp input to d m Y format.

Comment: Have you heard about [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)??

Comment: i saw strtotime and even had it in the echo string but it outputs time. I needed only date

Comment: check answer below!!!

Comment: i am reverting my database column to timestamp type again and applying below answer, will sure give the review

Comment: what the actual value you get from `$row['lastupdate']`? I think you don't have to use explode here.

Comment: The answer from Unni babu works, same for sherif. But aside from date, explode is quite useful function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so you know [date](http://php.net/date) expects an integer (*as a Unix timestamp from the epoch*) for its second argument, which is optional and by default is the current timestamp.

> **timestamp**
>
> The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In other words, it defaults to the value of time().

Second, `$x = explode('-',$row['lastupdate'],0)` is basically the same exact thing as saying `$x = array($row['lastupdate'])`, which doesn't make a lot of sense if you're handing `$x` to `date()`.

What you *probably* meant to do was something more along the lines of this...

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $row['lastupdate']);
$date = "$month.$day.$year";
```

Which just splits the formatted date string stored in MySQL by hyphen and reassembles the parts in the desired order. If the formatted date string contains anything other than just the date you can discard that bit as well by just splitting the string by space first, before splitting it by hyphen, like so...

```
// Say your $row['lastupdate'] string is '2015-07-18 13:29:00', for example
list($tmpDate) = explode(' ', $row['lastupdate'], 2);
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $tmpDate);
$date = "$month.$day.$year";
```

Now you get the desired `07.18.2015`.

---

Now, of course, you could also convert the formatted date string into a Unix timestamp first with `strtotime()`, and then try converting the Unix timestamp back into a formatted string using `date()` (*probably also something you were trying to do*), but you have to be aware of things like Timezones, which may or may not become problematic if you aren't carefully and fully understand the implications of what [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) does and how [MySQL deals with timezones](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), for example (*assuming you're also using MySQL somewhere else*).

Comment: This is brilliant, i was confused about explode function. I will use this technique for arrays next time. And the code worked pin point. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

**Use php date() and strtotime()**

```
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['lastupdate']));  // new date contains d-m-y format of lastupdate
```

Comment: Here's the code i gave `$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['lastupdate']));
   echo "<tr><td>".$newDate."</td><td>"`

Comment: Thanks, i had figured a string going wrong. your code worked. Thank You

Comment: @SachinKanungo..please select the checkbox to select this as answer :) always welcome

Comment: Your answer deserved same spot as sherif, but i feel his answer can provide good insight to new coders. Only if it was possible to make 2 best answers i would have done yours no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

you can use date_format mysql function like this

```
select date_format(now(), '%m-%d-%Y');
```